# htaccess Set RewriteBase to beginning of Request URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I set the RewriteBase in my .htaccess file to the first part of the REQUEST_URI (domain.com/path or domain.com/path/to/file would set RewriteBase to /path)?

Comment: Yes, I want it set to the first folder. I'm having trouble thinking of how to better word it. If you have any questions that might help better define it, I would be glad to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically set the `RewriteBase`, but you could, by hand, extract the first path from the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and manually add that to *absolute* URL-path targets. Example:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^foo$ /%1/bar.html [L]
```

Here, if that rule was in the htaccess file in the URL-path `/a/b/c`, and you request `/a/b/c/foo`, the rule would rewrite that as `/a/bar.html`.

Alternatively, if you have lots of rules and you absolutely need to the `%` backreferences, you can set it as an environment variable at the very top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:first_uri_path} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=first_uri_path:%1]

# then your rules:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^foo$ /%{ENV:first_uri_path}/bar.php?domain=%1 [L]
```

Not sure how feasible of a solution this is for you, depending on what you actually plan to do with "dynamic RewriteBases".

Comment: Not really what I was hoping to hear, but from my research there doesn't seem to be any better way. Thanks for answering!

Comment: year 2020 - and there are still no further usefull variables available in htaccess :-(